# DB2 update using inner join

Tags: db2, sql-update, inner-join

I want to make an UPDATE statement on a DB2 table using INNER JOIN
I try this

```
update TABLE1 set FIELDVALUE='text/html' from TABLE1 as T1 
inner join TABLE2 as T2 on T1.PROFILE_ID = T2.PROFILE_ID 
inner join TABLE3 as T3 on T2.MSGTYPE_ID = T3.MSGTYPE_ID 
where T1.NAME='contentType' and T3.NAME='Order';
```

I mention that the select works fine

```
select * from TABLE1 as T1 inner join TABLE2 as T2 
on T1.PROFILE_ID = T2.PROFILE_ID 
inner join TABLE3 as T3 on T2.MSGTYPE_ID = T3.MSGTYPE_ID 
where T1.NAME='contentType' and T3.NAME='Order';
```

Thanks!

Comment: Which version of DB2, on which platform?  I'm not sure if _any_ of them support using joins - the solution is to usually do some sort of subquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Db2 doesn't allow "update + join" syntax. But, you can rewrite your sql like this (not tested):

```
update TABLE1 set FIELDVALUE='text/html' 
where table1.primary_key in (
(
    select t1.primary_key
    TABLE1 as T1 
    inner join TABLE2 as T2 on T1.PROFILE_ID = T2.PROFILE_ID 
    inner join TABLE3 as T3 on T2.MSGTYPE_ID = T3.MSGTYPE_ID 
    where T1.NAME='contentType' and T3.NAME='Order'
);
```